# Java sensor id to server

Tags: java

i am currently working on a assignment which uses phidgets. I have this code which outputs the phidgets details such as serial number, device version and its values. I can get it to print out the serial number into the console with

```
System.out.println("Serial Number " + phid.getSerialNumber());
```

How would i go about adding it into my String fullURL on my server?

```
String fullURL = sensorServerURL + "?sensorname=rotationsensor&sensorvalue="+sensorValue;
```

Any help will be appreciated, my assignment deadline is at 11pm tonight and this is been bugging me for a while, cant seem to figure it out :/

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import com.phidgets.InterfaceKitPhidget;
import com.phidgets.PhidgetException;
import com.phidgets.event.AttachEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.AttachListener;
import com.phidgets.event.DetachEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.DetachListener;
import com.phidgets.event.ErrorEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.ErrorListener;
import com.phidgets.event.InputChangeEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.InputChangeListener;
import com.phidgets.event.OutputChangeEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.OutputChangeListener;
import com.phidgets.event.SensorChangeEvent;
import com.phidgets.event.SensorChangeListener;

public class SensorToServer implements SensorChangeListener, InputChangeListener,
    AttachListener, DetachListener, ErrorListener, OutputChangeListener {

public static int LED_PORT=7;
public static int INPUT_PORT=3;
public static int ANALOG_PORT=7;
public static String sensorServerURL = "http://localhost:8080/SensorServer/sensorToDB";
 public static void main(String[] args) throws PhidgetException {

    new SensorToServer();
}

public SensorToServer() throws PhidgetException {

    InterfaceKitPhidget phid = new InterfaceKitPhidget();

    try {

        phid.addAttachListener(this);
        phid.addDetachListener(this);
        phid.addSensorChangeListener(this);
        phid.addInputChangeListener(this);
        //phid.addOutputChangeListener(this);
        phid.openAny();

        phid.waitForAttachment();

        System.out.println(phid.getDeviceType());
        System.out.println("Serial Number " + phid.getSerialNumber());
        System.out.println("Device Version " + phid.getDeviceVersion());

        System.out.println("Looping...\n");
        boolean led = true;
        boolean dummy = true;
        for (; dummy;) {

            phid.setOutputState(LED_PORT, led);
            if (!phid.getInputState(INPUT_PORT))
                led = !led;
            try {
                // changing the output too often seems to mess up the sensor
                // box
                // Thread.sleep(100 + phid.getSensorValue(7));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                // Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        phid.close();
        System.out.println("Closed and exiting...");
    }
  }

 public void sensorChanged(SensorChangeEvent arg0) {
    // System.out.println(arg0);
        int sensorValue = arg0.getValue();
    System.out.println("Slider value is now "+sensorValue);
    String sendResult = sendToServer(sensorValue);
    try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping.... 1 sec");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   System.out.println("Sent to server, result: "+sendResult);
}
public void inputChanged(InputChangeEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}

public void attached(AttachEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}

public void detached(DetachEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}

public void error(ErrorEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}

public void outputChanged(OutputChangeEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}
public String sendToServer(int sensorValue){
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    BufferedReader rd;
    String fullURL = sensorServerURL + "?sensorname=rotationsensor&sensorvalue="+sensorValue;
   System.out.println("Sending data to: "+fullURL);
    String line;
    String result = "";
    try {
       url = new URL(fullURL);
       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
       rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          result += line;
       }
       rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "done : "+result;
//        return result;

}
}
```

Comment: Can't you save the serialNumber on a variable and build your `fullUrl` with another parameter?    `fullURL = sensorServerURL + "?sensorname=rotationsensor&sensorvalue="+sensorValue+"&serialNumber="+serialNumberVariable;`

Comment: You need to add it as parameters to url, you have already sth similar like this &sensorvalue="+sensorValue. You need for instance &serialNumber=phid.getSerialNumber() add to url. Unfortunately to handle it correctly You need make some changes of server side.